# Codeigniter Join 2 Table with array value

Tags: codeigniter-3, join

I have a database with 2 tables Movies and Genre. Movies Table genres has array value. 
    Now when I query it come like this

```
    id      movie name        genres
    1. Adventure        -    1, 2
```

But I want to join these 2 table and and display value like

```
   id      movie name        genres
    1.    Adventure        -    action, adventure
```

These are my two table

```
Movie Genres table

id   | name    | slug
1    action      action
2    adventure   adventure
3    comedy      comedy

Movies table

id | movie_name |    genres
1  | Avengers   |     1,2
```

Need help thank you

Comment: seems like you have to look for normalization..

Comment: Well as you have designed the database you must have created the mysqli statements for testing it... then it's just a matter of adhering to the documentation for the query builder to convert it?

Answer (score 0):

You can run following query to get this result

```
SELECT m.id, m.movie_name, GROUP_CONCAT(g.name) as genres
FROM movie m
INNER JOIN genres g
  on FIND_IN_SET(g.id, m.genres)
GROUP BY m.id
```

Check on SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40a438/2

In codeigniter,

```
$this->db->select("m.id, m.movie_name, GROUP_CONCAT(g.name) as genres");
$this->db->from("movie m");
$this->db->join("genres g", "FIND_IN_SET(g.id, m.genres)", "inner");
$this->db->group_by("m.id");
$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: I think This is for single row Query. But I want all row

Comment: Just add $this->db->group_by("m.id");
It will select all rows. (Please check updated answer now)